# Swarm installation and Setup for perforce

Tags: php, apache, perforce, swarm

I am getting "Internal Server error" while running swarm. Can anybody help me with the installtion and setup. However I referred installation process but something is still not goo.

Comment: That sounds like your web server is not configured properly. Perforce Technical Support can help you with that.

Comment: Check your Swarm log and your Apache log. Usually that means Swarm can't reach your Perforce server or doesn't have the access it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the time to respond to that post cause I'd a similar problem and the solution is a bit tricky.

If you use a security level that require ticket, you need to set the ticket (and not the password) in the configuration file : /opt/perforce/swarm/data/config.php

Comment: This was the case for us, as well. Also don't forget to set up the triggers, like I did!